# Fail2ban bantime.increment not working

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I wanted to increase the bantime of repeat offenders getting caught by fail2ban. I added the following lines at the top of /etc/fail2ban/jail.local and fail2ban.local

```
[DEFAULTS]
bantime.increment = true
bantime.factor = 1
bantime.formula = ban.Time * (1<<(ban.Count if ban.Count<20 else 20)) * banFactor
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Here's a part of the log

```
2022-02-12 12:18:11,869 fail2ban.filter         [744]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 193.56.29.112 - 2022-02-12 12:18:11
2022-02-12 12:18:11,888 fail2ban.actions        [744]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Ban 193.56.29.112
2022-02-12 12:28:11,985 fail2ban.actions        [744]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Unban 193.56.29.112
2022-02-12 12:28:29,103 fail2ban.filter         [744]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 193.56.29.112 - 2022-02-12 12:28:29
2022-02-12 12:36:15,501 fail2ban.filter         [744]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 193.56.29.112 - 2022-02-12 12:36:15
2022-02-12 12:36:15,928 fail2ban.actions        [744]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Ban 193.56.29.112
2022-02-12 12:46:16,257 fail2ban.actions        [744]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Unban 193.56.29.112
2022-02-12 12:46:42,148 fail2ban.filter         [744]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 193.56.29.112 - 2022-02-12 12:46:42
```

Could there be something overriding this? How can I find out?

My server is Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bantime increment facility is released with fail2ban 0.11, so if you see 0.11.x by `fail2ban-client --version` it must work.

As for the issue, please read the mans attentively (what exactly and where exactly you've to specify that).

Anyway you have to set `bantime.increment = true` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` (not in `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.*`) for certain jail(s) or even in **DEFAULT** section, if must be valid for all jails.

Take careful look at your [jail.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/246d0e1100943e35c9e799463f152621bd35a2b2/config/jail.conf#L41), do you see `S` in default section name?

Thus remove the `S` like in this diff and it'd work...

```
-[DEFAULTS]
+[DEFAULT]
 bantime.increment = true
```

(and you don't need to set `bantime.factor` and `bantime.formula` since they seem to be default values).